# Shiny App Fails Without Trailing Slashes

Tags: nginx, shiny, reverse-proxy, shiny-server, proxypass

I am running a Shiny server behind a proxy as instructed [in this post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy).

URL with trailing slashes http://yhat.io/shiny/faithful/ works as expected.

However, the URL http://yhat.io/shiny/faithful (without trailing slashes)

gets redirected to http://yhat.io/faithful/, and it fails with 404 not found.

Here is my `nginx` configuration,

```
location /shiny/ {
                rewrite ^/shiny/(.*)$ /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
                proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/shiny/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_read_timeout 20d;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }
```

Here is my nginx `access.log`,

```
147.158.2.202 - - [20/Jan/2018:06:25:41 +0000] "GET /shiny/faithful/__sockjs__/n=9D3bkci4UbDJVuOKzw/866/05qfjneq/websocket HTTP/1.1" 101 19667 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ...
147.158.2.202 - - [20/Jan/2018:06:25:39 +0000] "GET /faithful/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ..
```

I am wondering why the `rewrite` regex does not capture the trailing slashes? URL without trailing slashes gets redirected to port 80 instead of `Shiny` port 3838.

I have tried a various solution, including

- `rewrite ^(/shiny/[^/]+)$ $1/ permanent;` as suggested by @Dean Attali
- `location ~ ^/shiny/?$` to enable regex matching
- comment out `location \`

Unfortunately, nothing works so far. Can someone point me in a direction?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies guys. After much tinkering, I conclude that @DeanAttali's suggestion actually works.

```
rewrite ^(/shiny/[^/]+)$ $1/ permanent;
```

The problem lies in ***my*** Chrome agent and it is an isolated issue. Unfortunately, I still cannot figure out the reason behind.

There are 2 tips I may share in case someone faces the similar situation in the future.

1. Try out various browser types by using **User-Agent Spoofer** to validate your problem.
2. Instead of refreshing manually on your browser, use `curl -L` to test result.

On command line,

```
$ curl -L yhat.io/shiny/faithful | head -n 10 

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   194  100   194    0     0    194      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  1083
100  2257  100  2257    0     0   2257      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  2257
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.0.5];ionrangeslider[2.1.6];strftime[0.9.2];bootstrap[3.3.7]</script>
<script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```